# @Configuration not applied depending on names of classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Please read the "Update" at the bottom. It seems to be a problem with  the name of the controllers. Depending on the name the SSL-configuration is not applied.

---

The `UserService` of my spring application connects to an external server that uses a self-signed cert in development. I added the self-signed and valid cert to a java key store `./dev-truststore.jks` and use this `@Configuration`:

```
@Profile("development")
@Configuration
class SSLConfigDev {
  @Suppress("unused")
  @PostConstruct
  private fun configureSSL() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "./dev-truststore.jks")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "secret")
  }
}
```

This is the reduced `UserServiceImpl` that still shows the error:

```
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak
// ...

@Service
class UserServiceFeatureImpl(
  private val userRepository: UserRepository,
  private val kc: Keycloak,
) : UserService {
  override suspend fun createUser(email: String, pw: String) {
    try {
      val realmResources = kc.realm("myRealm")
      val usersResource = realmResources.users()
      
      // The next line works fine until I define the new TaskService as 
      // described below. Then it fails with the SSL exception shown below.
      val existingUsers = usersResource.search(email, 0, 1)

      // ...
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      throw CreateAccountException("Could not create account", e)
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the route for creating users:

```
@RestController
class UserController(
  private val userService: UserService,
) {
  @PostMapping("/users/new")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  suspend fun create(@RequestBody @Valid dto: CredentialsDTO) {
    userService.createUser(dto.email, dto.password)
  }
}
```

This is the bean creation for `Keycloak`:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("keycloak")
class KeycloakConfig{
  lateinit var serverUrl: String
  lateinit var realm: String
  lateinit var clientId: String
  lateinit var clientSecret: String
  lateinit var frontEndClientId: String

  @Bean
  fun init(): Keycloak {
    return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
      .serverUrl(serverUrl)
      .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
      .realm(realm)
      .clientId(clientId)
      .clientSecret(clientSecret)
      .resteasyClient(
        ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()
      )
      .build()
  }
}
```

**This works fine.**

Now, I was developing a new unrelated feature (controller/service/repository) and suddenly the create-user route stops working, because it cannot connect to the keycloak service anymore because it fails to perform the SSL handshake. Note that the create-user action is not related to anything in the new service/feature and has not been modified.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The full stack trace is:

```
2021-06-25 18:04:19.050 ERROR 7821 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [755b0875-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/users/new"

com.example.backend.user.CreateAccountException: Could not create account
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl.createUser$suspendImpl(UserServiceFeatureImpl.kt:278) ~[main/:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.example.backend.user.UserController#create(CredentialsDTO, Continuation) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ com.example.backend.core.ReactorContextLocaleWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/users/new" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl.createUser$suspendImpl(UserServiceFeatureImpl.kt:278) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl.createUser(UserServiceFeatureImpl.kt) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed9e17ac.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ccf6d25.createUser(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl.createUser$suspendImpl(UserServicePermissionsImpl.kt:47) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl.createUser(UserServicePermissionsImpl.kt) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d7f96f3a.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fb5d3241.createUser(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserController.create$suspendImpl(UserController.kt:116) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserController.create(UserController.kt) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d1552207.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at com.example.backend.user.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dbf2c8.create(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
        at kotlin.reflect.full.KCallables.callSuspend(KCallables.kt:55) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
        at org.springframework.core.CoroutinesUtils$invokeSuspendingFunction$mono$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesUtils.kt:64) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:377) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.MonoKt.monoInternal$lambda-2(Mono.kt:90) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactor-1.5.0.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        // ...
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:469) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:261) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.request(FluxReceive.java:130) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollect.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:170) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:168) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:147) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:328) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:443) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:149) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.grantToken(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:90) ~[keycloak-admin-client-13.0.1.jar:13.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:70) ~[keycloak-admin-client-13.0.1.jar:13.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:65) ~[keycloak-admin-client-13.0.1.jar:13.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52) ~[keycloak-admin-client-13.0.1.jar:13.0.1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:579) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:440) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:149) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.search(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl.createUser$suspendImpl(UserServiceFeatureImpl.kt:247) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl.createUser(UserServiceFeatureImpl.kt) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed9e17ac.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServiceFeatureImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ccf6d25.createUser(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl.createUser$suspendImpl(UserServicePermissionsImpl.kt:47) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl.createUser(UserServicePermissionsImpl.kt) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d7f96f3a.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserServicePermissionsImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fb5d3241.createUser(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserController.create$suspendImpl(UserController.kt:116) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserController.create(UserController.kt) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d1552207.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at com.example.backend.user.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dbf2c8.create(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
    at kotlin.reflect.full.KCallables.callSuspend(KCallables.kt:55) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
    at org.springframework.core.CoroutinesUtils$invokeSuspendingFunction$mono$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesUtils.kt:64) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-release-749 (1.5.0)]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:377) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.MonoKt.monoInternal$lambda-2(Mono.kt:90) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactor-1.5.0.jar:na]
    // ...
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:168) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:147) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1215) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1475) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1381) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:323) ~[resteasy-client-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1324) ~[na:na]
    ... 122 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 127 common frames omitted

2021-06-25 18:04:19.072  INFO 7821 --- [or-http-epoll-3] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : 127.0.0.1:59138 - - [25/Jun/2021:18:04:18 +0200] "POST /users/new HTTP/1.1" 500 23140 306 ms
```

I tracked the issue down by removing all methods from the new service (so it is an empty interface + the implementation in a `@Service` annotated class):

```
interface TaskService {}
```

and

```
@Service
class TaskServiceImpl(
  // next line implies the error.
  private val userService: UserService,
) : TaskService {}
```

**When I remove the `private val userService: UserService` dependency from the `TaskServiceImpl` the `userService` is able to connect to keycloak and the create-user route does not fail, but if I add it again, the said SSL handshake error occurs on the create-user route.**

Other services, that also depend on the `UserService` as well, do not imply the same error. The new service is completely empty, so I am very confused why the other services do not imply the same error?

For example, this service also uses the `UserService` and it does **not** imply the user creation route to fail:

```
@Service
class FeedServiceImpl(
  private val userService: UserService,
  // other dependencies
) : FeedService {
   /// ...
}
```

The `TaskService` is used in two controllers, I have removed all routes and all other dependencies:

```
@RestController
class TaskReviewController(
  // adding or removing this dependency does not change anything
  private val taskService: TaskService,
) {
}
```

```
@RestController
class ActionsController(
  // adding or removing this dependency implies the error
  private val taskService: TaskService,
) {
}
```

When I remove the `taskService` dependency from both, the error does **not** occur. When I only add it to the `ActionsController` the error **does occur** - but if I only add it to the `TaskReviewController` the error does **not** occur.

I am lost how I can track it further down. I thought that this might indicate a dependency cycle but there isn't a cycle, as `UserService` does not depend on anything of the new `TaskService` and has not been modified when adding the new `TaskService`. And the `UserService` also has no dependency on any of the controllers.

Any ideas?

--

- spring-boot 2.5.0
- org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:13.0.1

PS: I also verified that `configureSSL` is still executed and I am running the right `development` profile.

## UPDATE

I found out that the error depends on the package and name of the controller. If all controllers that use the `TaskService` are alphabetically ordered after the `SSLConfigDev` configuration than the error does not occur:

So this controller in the same package as the 'SSLConfigDev` implies the error:

```
@RestController
class SSLConfigDeuController(
  private val taskService: TaskReviewService,
) {
}
```

but this is fine:

```
@RestController
class SSLConfigDewController(
  private val taskService: TaskReviewService,
) {
}
```

Comment: Probably your UserService depends on HTTP-client (Spring RestTemplate or Apache HttpClient), that uses default SSL context. You should configure two http clients with separate SSL contexts and inject non-SSL http client into UserService

Comment: yes, it uses a RestEasy client to connect to keycloak, but why would that work before then? Why does this problem not occur when other services `@Autowire` the `UserService`? There are ~20 other services already.

Comment: Did you try adding `-Djavax.net.debug=all` for verbose details? can you add relevant dependencies to question? Is your new service using HTTPClient and not RESTEasy ?

Comment: @user7294900 the new service interface and its implementation is completely empty, so it is not using any http client. The `UserService` interface and its implementation is quite complex. I will add a minimal version of it that still shows the error later when I have more time. But I am still very confused, why this problem would not occur when other services add the `UserService` as dependency and thought of a dependency issue that might result from the name of the new service and the ordering on the classpath or so...?

Comment: sounds as circular dependency, do you have aspect specific code?

Comment: @user7294900 do you ask if we have custom aspects? no. But we do have 2 implementations for all services and use a qualifier to select them and have one of the implementations marked as `@Primary`. But my guess is that this is unrelated. I wonder about the dep.circle... because the new service is not used anywhere.

Comment: I removed all code from the `UserService` and reduced it to a minimal version that still shows the error. I added the code to the question.

Comment: Ok, I found out that it has to do with the name of the services. So I guess it is a bug in how spring resolves dependencies and the alphabetic order of the names? I renamed the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I think I understand the problem.

Depending on the name of the controller the user service is instantiated before or after the `SSLConfigDev` configuration.

The `UserService` depends on `Keycloak`. The `Keycloak` class creates a resteasy client in the constructor:

The relevant code of the library is:

```
Keycloak(String serverUrl, String realm, String username, String password, String clientId, String clientSecret, String grantType, Client resteasyClient, String authtoken) {
        config = new Config(serverUrl, realm, username, password, clientId, clientSecret, grantType);
        client = resteasyClient != null ? resteasyClient : newRestEasyClient(null, null, false);
        authToken = authtoken;
        tokenManager = authtoken == null ? new TokenManager(config, client) : null;

        target = (ResteasyWebTarget) client.target(config.getServerUrl());
        target.register(newAuthFilter());
    }
```

This code is run when the `UserService` is instantiated because it triggers creating the `Keycloak` bean.

**Depending on whether this happens before or after the `SSLConfigDev` is run the system properties are already set or not.**

As often with the hard-to-spot bugs, solving the problem is easy:
We just need to ensure that the `Keycloak` bean is created after the system properties have been set. And because the correct configuration should not depend on the order of bean creation, the implementation should be bound to the specific bean.

For example, we can remove the `SSLConfigDev` and instead create a dev-profile version of the `Keycloak.init()` method that sets the system properties just before creating the bean instance. Or we can just check the environment when creating the bean as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("keycloak")
class KeycloakConfig(
  private val env: Environment,
){
  lateinit var serverUrl: String
  lateinit var realm: String
  lateinit var clientId: String
  lateinit var clientSecret: String
  lateinit var frontEndClientId: String

  @Bean
  fun init(): Keycloak {
    if (env.activeProfiles.contains("development")) {
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "./dev-truststore.jks")
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "keycloak")
    }
    return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
      .serverUrl(serverUrl)
      .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
      .realm(realm)
      .clientId(clientId)
      .clientSecret(clientSecret)
      .resteasyClient(
        ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()
      )
      .build()
  }
}
```